# awk how to replace white spaces with new line AND remove empty lines at the same time?

Tags: awk

I am trying to count the number of each word in a txt file.

words.txt

```
the day is sunny the the
the sunny is is
```

expected result:

```
the 4
is 3
sunny 2
day 1
```

I want to

1) replace all spaces with new line

```
awk -v RS=" " '{print}' words.txt
```

result

```
the
day
is
sunny
the
the
the
sunny
is
is
    #empty line
```

2) remove empty lines

```
awk 'NF>0 {print}' words.txt |sort | uniq -c |sort -bnr
```

result

```
1 the sunny is is
1 the day is sunny the the
```

How do I merge above 2 scripts into 1 line of code to produce expected result?

Comment: Is it a requirement that you use `awk`?  Or is a pipeline of other common Unix tools acceptable?

Comment: you need to insert a awk to filter line on length, this gave you an ugly `awk -v RS=" " 'NF>0 {print}' words.txt | awk 'length' | sort | uniq -c |sort -bnr`

Comment: @JigglyNaga, it's actually from Leetcode question # 192: https://leetcode.com/problems/word-frequency/ you are free to use any commands

Comment: @Archemar, great thanks it works! am trying to understand the relationship between | awk 'length' | and NF>0. Because without | awk 'length' | , system will still output blank lines despite NF>0. Could you share a bit on this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no real need to preprocess the text by changing spaces to newlines etc. especially not if you want to combine the operations into a single `awk` script.

```
$ awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) count[$i]++ } END { for (word in count) print count[word], word }' file
4 the
2 sunny
3 is
1 day
```

This walks over each whitespace-separated word and counts it. The counts are stored in the array `count` which is indexed by the words.  At the end, the counts and the corresponding words are outputted.  This would skip empty lines automatically, as they contain no words.

If you need this sorted, pipe it through `sort -n`.

If you use GNU `awk`, you can use its `asorti()` function to do the sort in the `END` block:

```awk
END {
    n = asorti(count, c2, "@val_num_desc")
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++ )
        printf("%d %s %s\n", i, count[c2[i]], c2[i])
}
```

Comment: @Archemar, thanks for the edit, but we don't really know what `awk` the user is using. I modified the text that you added.

Comment: I've always found asort() and asorti() kinda clunky, you could just set PROCINFO["sorted_in"] if you're using gawk (newer versions).

Comment: @EdMorton I've personally never used either. That piece of the answer was inserted by Archemar.  I would sort outside of `awk` (my default `awk` is not GNU `awk`).

Comment: In your first script instead of piping to `sort -n` you could just change `END{ for` to `END{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for` and leave the rest alone. It's an extremely useful feature (but not a big deal in this case).

Answer (score 0):

@Kusalananda already provided a good awk solution but alternatively:

```
$ tr ' ' '\n' < file | sort | uniq -c
      1 day
      3 is
      2 sunny
      4 the
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep, you can use the `-o` (`--only-matching`) option to display one match per line:

```
grep -o '\S\+' words.txt
```

Then pipe to `sort` and `uniq` as before.